# Selenium web driver Date picker exists in page after the send keys?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using send keys to input the value in date picker.. this is working absolutely fine, but most of the times date picker still displaying in the page after the send keys!! any idea how to remove date picker in page after the send keys???

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What happen when you input data manually?

Comment: It closes.. I mean disappear in page

Comment: I mean in this case we are doing send keys right?? do we need to do any click operation to close it

Comment: Maybe. When you do it manually you press enter in the end?

Comment: it's a just click!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the date picker, the date picker will be close automatically.
But you use send keys to input the value, you should send the key Enter after it.
Try to do it manually.